# Line dependency in Vim

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I was thinking of a feature [naming it line dependency] that might be useful in Vim and other editors.

What is line dependency?

Let `S` be a set of line numbers in the current buffer with are exactly same. A subset `S'` (of `S`) marked as dependent implies that any change to any of the line `l` in `S'` is reflected in all of `S'`.

`S'` is updated according to the changes in the buffer, i.e. lines can be traced back to the initial point where they were made.

Use case: Automatically duplicate changes in multiple lines without recording the macro.

Is it possible to this in Vim? Are there any inherent difficulties in implementing this idea? Is there any fundamental flaw in this idea?

Comment: The main flaw is that code duplication should be tackled by refactoring, rather than by editor macros, to make code easier to read. If you keep writing the same lines over and over, you've got a design issue.

Comment: True if the sole purpose of the editor is to write ONLY code. There might be other instances where such a feature might be desirable. For example consider dependency b/w two regions[instead of restricting to lines] of the buffer in a latex file. Changes made in a region are automatically duplicated in the other region. I find this feature useful when a writing a proof with lot of equations.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that sounds reasonable. Although LaTeX itself has a very strong macro facility...

Comment: Do multicursors solve the problem? https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Comment: @Alex i haven't tried it but the gif looks promising :) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) can help edit multiple identical sections of text simultaneously. Hope this is what you are looking for.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Vimscript, you can hook into the modification of a "source" line via the `CursorMovedI` event, but it's harder to react to modifications via normal mode (p) and Ex commands (:put), maybe via `CursorHold` after a delay.

To keep track of the lines when there are insertions / deletions above, you can use marks, but there are only 26 of them.

The line updates can be "cloned" easily via `setline()`.

In general, doing this in Vimscript won't be perfect and difficult to implement. Adding this to core Vim would require in-depth knowledge of the Vim internals and source code, and is unlikely to be accepted by Vim's maintainer. Think hard whether that's really worth it.